# Switch v-sync on runtime, using HaxeFlixel c++ target

Tags: rendering, haxe, haxeflixel, vsync, haxelib

Is it possible to switch `vsync` on/off for my `HaxeFlixel` project, on runtime? Or do I have to create different executable files (one with vsync enabled, and another one with `vsync` disable)

After dealing with an [IntelHD bug](https://github.com/openfl/lime/issues/390), I had to [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35820845/windows-cpp-target-slows-down-in-higher-resolutions/36224429#36224429) `vsync` for my C++ target, using this build setting:

```xml
<window if="cpp" width="960" height="540" fps="60" background="#000000" hardware="true" vsync="false" antialiasing="0" />
```

It would be nice to switch it from the game menu, so I'm wondering if there is an API that enables/disables `vsync` on runtime.

Comment: Are you using OpenFL legacy (Flixel's default) or next?

Comment: Yes, the default OpenFL..